# How long to keep Stripe webhook event record for idempotence?

Tags: mongodb, design-patterns, stripe-payments, webhooks

My app implements Stripe webhooks. I save a record of the ID of the event after I've processed it and check against these records before I process each webhooks. So my app is currently idempotent as per the Stripe docs best practices: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices

However how long do I need to keep these records? Should I keep them forever or can I delete them after 30 days, 6 months, 1 year, etc?

I store them in a Mongo DB and the data is just the ID of the Stripe webhook event so the collection data looks like after a few years (I only listen to a few events):

COLLECTION SIZE: 2.73MB
TOTAL DOCUMENTS: 47183
INDEXES TOTAL SIZE: 1.51MB

Eventually this collection will get really big and every time I query it to check the latest webhook that query will get slower. But I imagine this will take quite a long time to really matter.

What is the software best practice here? I was in the process of writing a cron to delete
after 14 days but I thought to myself is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve events older than 30 days: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list so if you need to contents, you should keep them.

If you need the latest event ID, you should store that, or index on event ID, or store a list of just datetime,event_id.

Comment: I dont need the content of these messages as I have already actioned whatever they are telling my app. This is more just about ensuring I never get fault re triggers of events. If the API won't retrieve events older than 30 days then I think I can assume that they couldn't be accidentally sent to my app either.